# Method code in c# serialization

Tags: c#

When an object is serialized (by remoting to be sent across the wire) does the instance method code get serialized? Or are just the class level instance fields serialized?

I am asking this as some of my objects have large method and want to know wheather I should be using DTO's (data transfer objects) for sending data across the wire.

I guessing it's just the data plus some type version data ... am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are never serialized.

Re "fields" - it all depends on the serializer; `BinaryFormatter` will do fields; you mention "remoting", which suggests `BinaryFormatter`, but remoting is largely a hangover now - from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx) (on remoting):

> This topic is specific to a legacy
>   technology that is retained for
>   backward compatibility with existing
>   applications and is not recommended
>   for new development. Distributed
>   applications should now be developed
>   using the Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF).

If you use web-services or WCF: `XmlSerializer` does public fields+properties; `DataContractSerializer` will do marked fields, etc.

Regular classes are often reusable as DTOs, but if you need lots of control over the wire (or have versioning issues), a separate DTO can be helpful.

---

(edit/additional) note also that there are other reasons not to like `BinaryFormatter` - it can be **very** brittle with versioning, and very painful to fix (although achievable). Other (more tolerant) serializers exist if this is likely to be an issue... if so, let me know and I'll update.

Comment: I would just mention that XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer cannot serialize circular references. NetDataContractSerializer can: http://coding-time.blogspot.com/2008/03/serialize-object-graph-to-xml-in-net.html

Comment: @Martin: actually, DataContractSerializer can too. You just need to enable it (the `preserveObjectReferences` ctor argument).

Comment: remoting is not legacy technology and it has several usage scenarios that are not possible with WCF.

Comment: They are Microsoft's words; I suggest their opinion may be worth noting. The biggest use of remoting (going forward) may be comms between AppDomains that the developer never knows about. Also; that logic is circular: WCF also allows several usage scenios that are not possible with remoting... I'm not sure that makes either better or worse - just different.

Answer (score 0):

What gets saved is the data plus tags corresponding to your class and property names. The code itself doesn't get serialized.